# Need help echoing an include that is linked to another echo

Tags: php, templates, include, echo

I have a 3 php files where i am trying to echo an include from a page.php to template.php but the include is another php file (Slideshow.php) it works but is positioned in the wrong place

The result needs to be like this:
http://st-margarets-barking.org.uk/SchoolDay.php

the codes i have are:

template.php:

```
<body>

<?php echo $slideshow; ?>

</body>
```

page.php:

```
<?php
$content = "content";
$slideshow = include("Slideshow.php");
$template = "template.php";
require($template);
?>
```

Slideshow.php:

```
<?php echo "<img src='Images/slideshow-frame.png' style='position:relative; top:-20px;'>
<div class='cycle-slideshow slideshow-width' data-cycle-speed='500' data-cycle-timeout='5000'>
<img src=Images/slides/041214%20Assembly%20(5).png>
<img src=Images/slides/Evacuation-Day-001.png>
<img src=Images/slides/Trewern-002.png>
<img src=Images/slides/church-silhouette.png>
<img src=Images/slides/Evacuation-Day-003.png>
</div>";
?>
```

The result is this:
http://st-margarets-barking.org.uk/SchoolDay0.php

I have tried:

page.php

```
$slideshow = "<?php include('Slideshow.php');";
```

However this shows a server error

I can do this:

template.php:

```
<?php include("Slideshow.php"); ?>
```

This works, but then I have to create more template.php as well as more Slideshows.php, this is not what I want to do

the point of this is to have different slideshow.php files so I can change the slideshow in the page.php, then the template.php will echo the slideshow and all other content on the page.php, this will save me time of having to change the slideshow images on each page.php

can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you look at the source thats send to the browser, you'll see "  include ('Slideshow.php');   ".  $slideshow = include("Slideshow.php"); probably isn't wrapped in PHP tags.

Comment: the whole page.php is wrapped in php tags, sorry i probably should have included that

Comment: Return the images  from Slideshow.php instead of echoing them.  $slideshow is probably being set to null.

Comment: Sorry im kind of a beginner in php, i dont really understand terms like "return" or what i would have to do to "return the images"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display the content of Slideshow.php inside template.php, you have to change it like this:

```
<?php 
function images() {
    $str =  "<img src='Images/slideshow-frame.png' style='position:relative; top:-20px;'>
    <div class='cycle-slideshow slideshow-width' data-cycle-speed='500' data-cycle-timeout='5000'>
    <img src=Images/slides/041214%20Assembly%20(5).png>
    <img src=Images/slides/Evacuation-Day-001.png>
    <img src=Images/slides/Trewern-002.png>
    <img src=Images/slides/church-silhouette.png>
    <img src=Images/slides/Evacuation-Day-003.png>
    </div>";
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Then call the method inside page.php like:

```
include("Slideshow.php");    
$slideshow = images();
```

Comment: Wow, perfect that works perfectly, thank you, ill keep this in mind for next time :)